# Textencoding on Mac

Tags: macos, angular, filesaver.js

I got an Angular application which uses Filesaver.js for saving a plain text file to the file system. The encoding is UTF-8 without BOM.

Here is the problem:
When I open this file in Word on a Mac the umlauts are corrupted with strange signs. When I open the file with TextEdit it looks perfectly fine. If I save the file with TextEdit and open the saved file with Word on Mac it works as well.

Does anyone have a clue on how to resolve this?

Comment: Microsoft Office notoriously sucks when it comes to encodings. What file format exactly are you saving it as? .doc? .txt? What format are you saving it as in TextEdit?

Comment: I´m saving it as .txt - In TextEdit I just have to save it as is to make it work in Word.

Comment: So, Word cannot correctly detect the encoding of a plain text file, but TextEdit can. Using TextEdit to convert the file into a Word document enables Word to get it correct as well.

Comment: What a mess. Is there no way to give Word a hint on that?

Comment: You can try adding a BOM, but that has mixed results as well. It really, truly, plainly sucks.

Comment: Ok. We tried a BOM which did not have any effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved it using UTF 16 LE. Therefore we had to encode every single character in our string before saving it into a file.